# How to handle change in the $PWD value in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script executed by a tool. 
When it is executed by a this tool then the value of $PWD is set by that tool.
However when I executed the script manually the value of $PWD the current directory of script.

Now I'm using this $PWD environmental variable to locate different file location in the script.

But when I execute it manually the file path get changed and it give unexpected results.

Any suggestion how can I handle this change in the value of $PWD while executing the script manually or by that tool?

Comment: You can give the script the PWD as an optional parameter: if set, work with it. Otherwise, work as usual.

Comment: `PWD` usually refers to the current directory. If you want a variable to mean something else, why don't you use a different variable name?

Comment: @fedorqui in both cases by Manual or by tool execution of script value of $PWD is there but it is different :(

Comment: Would be useful to see some code, so we can guess where we can modify something to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the directory where the script itself is located, in bash you can use

```
script_dir=$(readlink -f ${0%/*})
```

It takes the relative path to the script (`$0`), cuts off the script name and transforms it to a full path.